# How can I retrieve the computer name with my Inno pascal script?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I've been having some difficulty with my inno pascal script. I familiarized myself a bit (just a bit)
with Pascal, but its becoming more clear to me now that pascal *script* may be very different.

The following code compiles fine with freepascal:

```
program test;

uses windows;

function GetPCName: string;
var
  buffer: array[0..MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1] of Char;
  Size: Cardinal;
begin
  Size := MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;
  Windows.GetComputerName(@buffer, Size);
  Result := StrPas(buffer);
end;

begin
   writeln('ComputerName: ' + (GetPCName));
   readln;
end.
```

How can I do something like this in my inno [code] section?
I tried the above, but it doesn't seem to like "uses windows;"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, you can use the builtin [`GetComputerNameString`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getcomputernamestring) support function.

You can declare a function in the code section to be able to call library functions. Something like the below should work:

```
[Code]
function GetComputerName(lpBuffer: AnsiString; var nSize: DWORD): BOOL;
external 'GetComputerNameA@kernel32.dll';

function GetPCName: string;
var
  Size: Cardinal;
  buffer: AnsiString;
begin
  Size := MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;
  SetLength(buffer, Size);
  GetComputerName(buffer, Size);
  Result := buffer;
end;
```

See 'codedll.iss' in the examples folder of inno setup.

Comment: Super, GetComputerNameString was all I wanted. I'll have to pour over the docs a bit more

Comment: I'm getting an error "Unknown identifier MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH "

Comment: @Jay - It's a define in winbase.h, it's value is 15.